# Sequelize - How To Design One To One Association?

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js, associations, one-to-one

I am creating two models, the first one is `User` and the second one is `Portfolio`. When a user is creating a `Portfolio` (where a user can only have one `Portfolio`), I want it to have reference to the user who is creating it, and every time that user's data is fetched, I want it to also fetching their portfolio data if any.

I am trying to use `hasOne` to create `portfolio_id` inside `User` tables, with the skeleton generated using `sequelize init` command, but it is not working. I cannot find a column the name `protfolio_id` if I don't put it inside the user migration file. Is that how it is supposed to be?

How should I design the models? Should I include the `portfolio_id` in `User` tables and include `user_id` in `Portfolio` table, or is there a best way to do it?

And which associations method should I use, hasOne or belongsTo?

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you are calling `Model.associate` for each model. This will run queries for all the relationships.

You can define the relationships in the associate method as follows:

```
// user.js (User Model definition)
module.exports = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
    const { STRING } = dataTypes
    const User = sequelize.define("user", {
        username: { type: STRING }
    })

    User.associate = models => {
        User.hasOne(models.Portfolio, { foreignKey: "userId" }) // If only one portfolio per user
        User.hasMany(models.Portfolio) // if many portfolios per user
    }

    return User
}

// portfolio.js (Portfolio Model definition)
module.exports = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
    const { STRING } = dataTypes
    const Portfolio = sequelize.define("portfolio", {
        portfolioName: { type: STRING }
    })

    Portfolio.associate = models => {
        Portfolio.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "userId" })
    }

    return Portfolio
}
```

---

**hasOne** stores the foreignKey in the target model. So this relationship will add a foreign key `userId` to the `Portfolio` model.

**belongsTo** stores the key in the current model and references the primary key of the target model. In this case the `Portfolio.belongsTo` will add `userId` in the `Portfolio` model which will reference the primary key of `User` model.

Notice how both these relationships do the same thing, they add userId to the Portfolio model. Its better to define this in both models for your last use case:

> I want it to have reference to the user who is creating it, and every time that user's data is fetched, I want it to also fetching their portfolio data if any.

**Accessing related models:**
In sequelize fetching a related model together with the main model is called **Eager Loading**. Read more about it [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading).

Now for your use case if you want to fetch the portfolio if any, while fetching user, do the following:

```
var userWithPortfolio = await User.findAll({include: [models.Portfolio]};
// Or you may also use include: {all: true} to include all related models.
var userWithPortfolio = await User.findAll({include: {all: true}};

/*  
    Output:

    userWithPortfolio = {
        username: "xyz",
        portfolio: {
            portfolioName: "xyz"
        }
    }
*/
```

Comment: Does it automatically create the `user_id` on `Portfolio` table when `sequelize db:migrate` is executed? Or is it not supposed to work like that, so I should manually define the foreign key in migration file?

Comment: If you are okay with losing data in database tables just run call `sequelize.sync({force: true})` after calling associate on all models. Calling `sync({force: true})` will **drop all tables** and create them from scratch using new definitions. If you don't want to lose data you will have to [create a migration for association](https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-define-sequelize-associations-using-migrations-de4333bf75a7) as shown in linked post

Comment: If the `Portfolio` table already has `user_id` that references `id` in `User` table then you might only need to restart the server